# How to get the total and available virtual memory as shown in the System information App in 64-bit in C++?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-10, 64-bit

How Do I get the total and available virtual memory as shown in the System information App in 64-bit (WIndows 10) programmatically in C++?  The ullTotalVirtual & ullAvailVirtual from the GlobalMemoryStatusEx() API is not giving me what I look for.  I am not looking for the total virtual address space.  I am looking for the actual system total and available virtual memory usages from the system settings.  I can't seem to find sample code of a differernt API for it.

If you run msinfo32.exe in Windows 10, you will get the the value like 36.7 GB and 20.5 GB for total and available respectively with 32 GB install memory.  Using the GlobalMemoryStatusEx() API, I would get the number in Terabytes.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I *think* msinfo32.exe (and even msinfo.exe) runs as a 32-bit process. Can you compile, build and run your code as 32-bit and see what the values you get are then?

Comment: ... I would certainly *expect* a 64-bit process running on Windows 10 to show VM in the Terabyte range.

Comment: Our App also has a 32-bit version and the GlobalMemoryStatusEx()  is giving us what we expect.  In 64-bit, it's not giving us what we're looking for like the results given by msinfo32.exe.  msinfo32.exe does it and I hope that someone would know how it does it or a way to do it.  Thanks.